# cmake and make resulting in different binary sizes when cross-compiling

Tags: c, linux, cmake, makefile, cross-compiling

I am cross-compiling to an ARM target in a Ubuntu 20.04 host machine.

The files I am building are from an SDK from Quectel, which already has makefiles and it builds fine.

My job is to translate the makefiles into a CMakeFileList.txt to do the same as the makefile does. That is already done.

### Procedure to translate makefiles to cmake

I ran the make with verbose mode, and then I collected all the flags that are set, linker options, compiler options, linker mapping, etc.

### Issue found on this

I noticed that the binary differs from what is built via the makefiles and what is built via CMakeList.txt, although they are working.

### Output from the original makefiles:

```sh
Memory region         Used Size  Region Size  %age Used
LOAD_IRAM_MCUVECTOR:         100 B        100 B    100.00%
   LOAD_IRAM_MCU:        4056 B       5020 B     80.80%
UNLOAD_DRAM_USRNV:          1 KB         1 KB    100.00%
   LOAD_DRAM_MCU:          48 B         4 KB      1.17%
UNLOAD_DRAM_PSPHYRET:          6 KB         6 KB    100.00%
       LOAD_IRAM:       32404 B        32 KB     98.89%
LOAD_DRAM_SHARED:      124448 B       156 KB     77.90%
   LOAD_DRAM_BSP:        3884 B         8 KB     47.41%
UNLOAD_DRAM_FLASHMEM:          7 KB         7 KB    100.00%
UNLOAD_DRAM_SLPMEM:         224 B        992 B     22.58%
       FLASH_APP:     2356204 B      2560 KB     89.88%
```

### Output from the CMakeList.txt developed:

```sh
Memory region         Used Size  Region Size  %age Used
LOAD_IRAM_MCUVECTOR:         100 B        100 B    100.00%
   LOAD_IRAM_MCU:        4056 B       5020 B     80.80%
UNLOAD_DRAM_USRNV:          1 KB         1 KB    100.00%
   LOAD_DRAM_MCU:          48 B         4 KB      1.17%
UNLOAD_DRAM_PSPHYRET:          6 KB         6 KB    100.00%
       LOAD_IRAM:       32404 B        32 KB     98.89%
LOAD_DRAM_SHARED:      124464 B       156 KB     77.91%
   LOAD_DRAM_BSP:        3884 B         8 KB     47.41%
UNLOAD_DRAM_FLASHMEM:          7 KB         7 KB    100.00%
UNLOAD_DRAM_SLPMEM:         224 B        992 B     22.58%
       FLASH_APP:     2354932 B      2560 KB     89.83%
```

As you can see, the difference is quite small, 3984 Bytes more in the CMakeList.txt case.

The compiler and linker used are the same:

```sh
arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
arm-none-eabi-gcc (GNU Toolchain for the Arm Architecture 11.2-2022.02 (arm-11.14)) 11.2.1 20220111
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

arm-none-eabi-ld --version
GNU ld (GNU Toolchain for the Arm Architecture 11.2-2022.02 (arm-11.14)) 2.37.20220122
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) a later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
```

**Question:** Is there a reason for this difference?

Comment: There could be 100 different reasons.  One common one is that cmake might be using fully-qualified pathnames for all the source files, while your makefile was using relative pathnames.  If you didn't strip the final result then the pathnames might be left in some part of the binary.  That's just one idea.

Comment: Both make and CMake invoke a compiler and linker. But most likely, these calls are performed with **different parameters**. Both building ways support a way to see that parameters, so you can easily find a difference.